# extract APK file contents using .NET tool

Tags: c#, android, apk

I used apktool to extract an APK file contents. But for some reasons I need such a tool written in .NET so I do not need to install the JDK in the server.

Is there such a tool?

Comment: Did you find a way to do this?

Comment: Not in .NET nor in Java. You need to use the APKTool. Google it and use it. Otherwise, write you own extractor in .NET but it is hard and need more efforts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. There is no such a tool. You need to start a Process in C# and run the batch file with the arguments using `ProcessStartInfo` class

Answer (score 0):

I think in another approach, take the APK file and create a Java program that extracts the info I need such as package name, icon resource etc... and then expose it as COM object and use it in my .NET project.

After deep research we can not extract that info in standard functions in Java, since the only way to extract the info is to unzip the APK via the APKTool and read the manifest from the file system.

Another way but hard is to write your own extractor which involves in deep knowledge in the format of the APK.